# How to force new fingerprint for all assets including old one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How would I force rails to generate new fingerprints for assets when pre-compile them?

Currently I just do:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

but it seems that some assets are still cached somewhere, thus, I need to generate new fingerprints for all assets, how would I do so?

I am using Rails 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config/initializers/assets.rb` you'll find this line:

```
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can ensure old assets are cleaned out

```
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:recompile
```

which would be better than leaving old assets lying around with old fingerprints.

NOTE: This will temporarily interrupt service on your production (if you do it in production) so not generally recommended.